# How can I create this kind of regression in R studio (regression with mean of previous lags)

Tags: r, regression

I need to forecast a certain regression with quarterly GDP data of selected countries.
I have the data of UK quarterly GDP from 2000 to 2010 and I want to forecast using this following regression:
Y_t = \alpha + \beta*((Y_{t-4}+Y_{t-5}+Y{t-6}+Y_{t-7})\4) + \epsilon
Does anyone know if I can use the arima function on R to explicit this kind of results?
Or will it more convenient to create another regressor and then forecast 2001Q4?
Thank you so much.

I tried using the xreg in the arima function like this

```
ArQoQ <- arima(data, order = c(0,0,0), xreg = (lag(data,7) + lag(data,6) + lag(data,5) + lag(data,4))\4)
```

It regresses and everything but when then I try to use the forecast function it keeps appearing an error.

Then when I tried by adding another regressor in a new_column:

```
fit <- data %>% model(lm=TSLM(Rate_percent ~ New_column)
```

Then the model does not work as it gives me a very low RSQ